# Keyboard shortcut to browse Time Machine file versions

Tags: macos, time-machine, keybindings

In some apps, e.g. Keynote and TextEdit, there is a built-in option to browse previous versions of a file using Time Machinve: File > Revert To > Browse All Versions.

Is there a way to browse these snapshots using keyboard shortcut or mouse/trackpad gesture, instead of clicking "Up" and "Down" buttons there?

[image]